# Javascript - validation services

Tags: javascript, validation

I found out that not a lot of questions on this website talk about validation services or how to check if a string it a phone number or a street address. I just wanted to start a question were people who are just learning javascript (like me) can get some insight into how checking with Regex. Everyone can enter a piece of code that validates a address or a phone number. And not going lo lie, I need to learn how to check a street address with Regex. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest having a look at a few sites that are particularly designed for this like http://regexr.com/, https://regexone.com/, http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: You can't use a regular expression to validate a street address as there are way too many different formats of street address. You might be able to use one if you define some limited subset of possible formats. Do you have one in mind?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple RegEx for Email validation for you to understand how to use RegEx for validation in JavaScript and for your requirement like Street Address, Its depends on you how you want your RegEx to be based on your Street Address format. You can modify this RegEx However you want.

```js
var value = 'vnykSJ@sj.com';
var streetAddRegEx = RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$').test(value);
console.log(streetAddRegEx);
```

Comment: Can't think why anyone would validate a **street** address as an email address.

Comment: Bro!! I just have an example how to use RegEx validation in Javascript.